# Code Excel VBA - my code go through the end but nothing change

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change 2 formulas and their conditions for 2 sheets that have the same cell in some Excel files within specific folders. When I run the code, the final MsgBox returned the result, but nothing changed. I don't even get any kind of error. I don't know why it is not working effectively. Please help!

```
Function IsInArray(value As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim element As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, value)) > -1)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Sub UpdateFormulasAndFormattingInFolders()
    Dim mainFolder As String
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim h15IconSet As IconSetCondition
    Dim j15Condition As FormatCondition
    
    mainFolder = "Mainfolder path" ' Update with the path to the main folder containing your subfolders
    
    Dim selectedFolders() As Variant 'Can be delete if all file are in one folder
    selectedFolders = Array("Ex1", "Ex2", "Ex3", "Ex4", "Ex5", "Ex6", "Ex7")
    
    
    ' Loop through each subfolder in the main folder
    Dim subfolder As String
    subfolder = Dir(mainFolder, vbDirectory)
    
    Do While subfolder <> ""
        
        
        ' Exclude the current folder (.) and parent folder (..)
        If subfolder <> "." And subfolder <> ".." Then
            
            
            ' Check if the current subfolder is in the selectedFolders array
            If IsInArray(subfolder, selectedFolders) Then
                Dim folderPath As String
                folderPath = mainFolder & subfolder & "\" 'Dir(mainFolder & "\" & subfolder)
                
                ' Loop through each Excel file in the folder
                filePath = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsx") 'only give the name of the file, NOT including the path
                Do While filePath <> ""
                    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filePath)
                    
                    ' Loop through each sheet in the Excel file
                    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
                        'Set calculation mode to automatic
                        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
                        ' Check if the sheet name is "S1" or "S2"
                        Select Case ws.Name
                            Case "S1", "S2"
                                ' Update the formula in cell H15 and set the format to percentage without decimals
                                ws.Range("H15").Formula = "=H33/G33"
                                ws.Range("H15").NumberFormat = "0%"
                                
                                ' Edit the rule for the existing icon set in cell H15
                                Set h15IconSet = ws.Range("H15").FormatConditions(1).IconSet
                                'h15IconSet.IconCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValueNumber
                                h15IconSet.IconCriteria(2).value = 0.75
                                
                                ' Update the formula in cell J15
                                ws.Range("J15").Formula = "=""A""& Text(" & ws.Range("H15").value & ",""0%"") & ""B"""
                                
                                ' Clear existing conditional formatting for cell J15
                                ws.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
                                
                                ' Add new conditional formatting rule to highlight cell J15 based on cell H15 value
                                Set j15Condition = ws.Range("J15").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="0.75")
                                j15Condition.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Highlight with red color for values less than 0.75
                                j15Condition.StopIfTrue = False
                                
                                Set j15Condition = ws.Range("J15").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreaterEqual, Formula1:="0.75")
                                j15Condition.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) ' Highlight with green color for values greater or equal to 0.75
                                j15Condition.StopIfTrue = False
                                ' Add other cases if you have more specific sheet names to update
                        End Select
                    Next ws
                    
                    ' Save and close the modified file
                    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
                    
                    filePath = Dir
                Loop
                ' Set calculation mode back to previous setting (optional)
                Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            End If
        End If
        ' Get the next subfolder
        subfolder = Dir
    Loop
    
    ' Notify the user when all folders have been processed
    MsgBox "Formulas and Conditional Formatting updated in all folders.", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: The MsgBox appears even if there were not any Do While ... Loop

Comment: You cannot have nested *Dirs*. You could first use *Dir* to write the found folder paths to a collection. Then you could loop through the collection and use *Dir* to open each file and do your thing. Instead of the function, you could simply do `If IsNumeric(Application.Match(subfolder, selectedFolders, 0)) Then`.

Answer (score 0):

### Process Worksheets in all Files Located in Specified Subfolders

- You cannot have nested Dirs. You could first use Dir to write the found folder paths to a collection. Then you could loop through the collection and use Dir to open each file and do your thing.

**Main**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Updates formulas and formats...
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub UpdateFormulasAndFormattingInFolders()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const ROOT_FOLDER_PATH As String = "C:\Test"
    Const DIR_FILE_PATTERN As String = "*.xlsx"
    Dim FolderNamesToMatch(): FolderNamesToMatch = Array( _
        "Ex1", "Ex2", "Ex3", "Ex4", "Ex5", "Ex6", "Ex7")
    Dim wsNames(): wsNames = Array("S1", "S2")
    Const SHOW_PROCESSING_ERROR_MESSAGE As Boolean = False
    
    ' Write the paths of the matching folders to a collection.
    
    Dim coll As Collection:
    Set coll = MatchingSubfolderPathsToCollectionOneLevel( _
        ROOT_FOLDER_PATH, FolderNamesToMatch)
    
    If coll Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No matching folders found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Loop through the items in the collection, open each workbook
    ' and use the 'UpdateFormulasAndFormatting' procedure
    ' to process each worksheet.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, Item, wsName
    Dim foCount As Long, wbCount As Long, wsCount As Long, wssCount As Long
    Dim WasFolderProcessed As Boolean, WasFileProcessed As Boolean
    Dim WasSheetProcessed As Boolean, IsFileToBeSaved As Boolean
    Dim Filename As String, FilePath As String
    
    For Each Item In coll ' through folder names (folders)
        
        Debug.Print String(30, "-") & vbLf; "Path: """ & Item & """"
        Filename = Dir(Item & DIR_FILE_PATTERN)
        
        Do While Len(Filename) > 0 ' through file names (workbooks)
            
            Debug.Print vbTab & "File: """ & Filename & """"
            FilePath = Item & Filename
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
            
            For Each wsName In wsNames ' through worksheet names (worksheets)
                ' Attempt to reference the worksheet.
                On Error Resume Next
                    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
                On Error GoTo 0
                ' Check if the attempt was successful.
                If Not ws Is Nothing Then ' worksheet exists
                    
                    ' Process the worksheet.
                    WasSheetProcessed = UpdateFormulasAndFormatting( _
                        ws, SHOW_PROCESSING_ERROR_MESSAGE)
                    
                    Debug.Print vbTab & vbTab & "Sheet: """ & wsName & """ (" _
                        & IIf(WasSheetProcessed, "Success", "Failure") & ")"
                    
                    ' Set the flags.
                    If Not WasFolderProcessed Then WasFolderProcessed = True
                    If Not WasFileProcessed Then WasFileProcessed = True
                    If WasSheetProcessed Then
                        If Not IsFileToBeSaved Then IsFileToBeSaved = True
                        wssCount = wssCount + 1
                    End If
                    wsCount = wsCount + 1
                    Set ws = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
                'Else ' worksheet doesn't exist; do nothing
                End If
            Next wsName
            
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=IsFileToBeSaved
            
            If IsFileToBeSaved Then ' at least one worksheet was updated
                IsFileToBeSaved = False ' reset for the next iteration
            'Else ' no worksheets were updated in the workbook; do nothing
            End If
            
            If WasFileProcessed Then ' at least one worksheet was processed
                wbCount = wbCount + 1
                WasFileProcessed = False ' reset for the next iteration
            'Else ' no worksheets were processed in the workbook; do nothing
            End If
            
            Filename = Dir
        
        Loop
        
        If WasFolderProcessed Then ' at least one worksheet was processed
            foCount = foCount + 1
            WasFolderProcessed = False ' reset for the next iteration
        'Else ' no worksheets were processed in the folder; do nothing
        End If
    
    Next Item
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
    ' Notify user.
    MsgBox "Processed " _
        & wsCount & " worksheet" & IIf(foCount = 1, "", "s") & " of " _
        & wbCount & " workbook" & IIf(foCount = 1, "", "s") & " located in " _
        & foCount & " folder" & IIf(foCount = 1, "", "s") & "." & vbLf & vbLf _
        & "Formulas and conditional formatting updated in " _
        & wssCount & " worksheet" & IIf(foCount = 1, "", "s") & ".", _
        IIf(wsCount = wssCount, vbInformation, vbCritical)

End Sub
```

**Help 1: Folders to Collection**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the paths of the level one subfolders of a folder,
'               in a collection.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function MatchingSubfolderPathsToCollectionOneLevel( _
    ByVal RootFolderPath As String, _
    ByVal FolderNamesToMatch As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal AppendTrailingPathSeparator As Boolean = True) _
As Collection
    
    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
    
    Dim RootPath As String: RootPath = RootFolderPath
    If Right(RootPath, 1) <> pSep Then
        RootPath = RootPath & pSep
    End If
    
    Dim FolderName As String: FolderName = Dir(RootPath, vbDirectory)
    
    Dim coll As Collection, FolderPath As String, IsFirstFound As Boolean
    
    Do While Len(FolderName) <> 0
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(FolderName, FolderNamesToMatch, 0)) Then
            If Not IsFirstFound Then
                Set coll = New Collection
                IsFirstFound = True
            End If
            FolderPath = RootPath & FolderName
            If AppendTrailingPathSeparator Then
                FolderPath = FolderPath & pSep
            End If
            coll.Add FolderPath
        End If
        FolderName = Dir
    Loop
        
    If IsFirstFound Then
        Set MatchingSubfolderPathsToCollectionOneLevel = coll
    End If

End Function
```

**Help 2: Process Single Worksheet**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Processes a single worksheet...
'               Returns a boolean indicating whether it was succesful.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function UpdateFormulasAndFormatting( _
    ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
    Optional ByVal ShowErrorMessage As Boolean = False) _
As Boolean
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Update Formulas and Formatting"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    With ws.Range("H15")
        .Formula = "=H33/G33" ' update the formula
        .NumberFormat = "0%" ' percentage without decimals
        ' Edit the rule for the existing icon set.
        With .FormatConditions(1).IconSet
            '.IconCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValueNumber
            .IconCriteria(2).value = 0.75
        End With
    End With

    With ws.Range("J15")
        .Formula = "=""A""& Text(" & ws.Range("H15").value _
            & ",""0%"") & ""B""" ' update the formula
        .FormatConditions.Delete ' clear existing formatting
        ' Highlight based on cell H15.
        With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, _
                Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="0.75")
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' or 'vbRed'; red
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
        With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, _
                Operator:=xlGreaterEqual, Formula1:="0.75")
            .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) ' green
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
    End With
    
    UpdateFormulasAndFormatting = True

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    If ShowErrorMessage Then
        MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
            & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    End If
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

**Final Message Box**

- My sheets were empty so of course, the processing failed.

[image]

**Immediate Window Results**

```
------------------------------
Path: "C:\Test\EX1\"
    File: "Test1.xlsx"
        Sheet: "S1" (Failure)
        Sheet: "S2" (Failure)
------------------------------
Path: "C:\Test\EX2\"
------------------------------
Path: "C:\Test\EX3\"
------------------------------
Path: "C:\Test\EX4\"
------------------------------
Path: "C:\Test\EX5\"
    File: "Test2.xlsx"
        Sheet: "S2" (Failure)
```